# Dynamically Create Ref in Constructor

Tags: reactjs

I want to make my child components have a ref, but I don't want the user to have to specify the ref when they create the component.  So say I have something like this:

```
<Parent>
    <Child />
    <Child />
</Parent>
```

And I want the parent to be able to access the Child components' state.  The easy way is to add a ref to each component, but I would like this to the be something that is done during the `constructor()` function to abstract this away from the end user, as I'd like these components to be generalized.

Is there a clean way to make it so the parent can access the state of the child components, such as when the Child is created you have something like:

```
class Child extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {'abc': 123}
        this.ref=Math.random();
    }
}
```

So that inside of the Parent class I can do something like:

```
 class Parent extends Component {
     componentWillMount(){
         console.log(this.refs);
     }
 }
```

So I want to be able to declare a set of components like:

```
class App extends Component {
    render(){
       <Parent> <Child /> <Child /> </Parent>
    }
}
```

So that I can access each child and it's state as the parent iterates through child components.

Comment: You can not access child component state from parent. State can be accessed, modified from it own class.

Comment: you actually can with a ref

Comment: I mean setting state of child component state from parent. You cant do this

Comment: check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864951/how-to-access-childs-state-in-react

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **I want the parent to be able to access the Child components' state.**

`State` is only accessible to component itself.  `Parent` and `child` component can access only their own state. You can pass value to child `state` as `props`  but parent can't access child component state itself.

2. Setting Refs to child component.

   Why do you want this? Ref is for
   **Managing focus, text selection, or media playback.

   Triggering imperative animations.

   Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.**

   Please visit this link to understand the uses of Ref.
   https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Anyway, components can have their own refs, and you can  set ref to child components,

```
render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child ref="child" />
        <div><button onClick={this.handleClick}>ACCESS REF</button></div>
      </div>
    );
  },

handleClick: function() {
    alert(this.refs.child.refs.input.getDOMNode().value);
  }
});

let Child = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <input ref="input" />;
  }
});
```

I will suggest , you should either pass callbacks into children as props to do your stuff.:

Comment: so you can't add a ref during the constructor?

Comment: you are totally going wrong way. First go through answer and link posted.

Comment: ehh, it's a weird use case, I'm repurposing React components for something outside of web dev so it might not be awful

Comment: how would you set the ref on create?

Comment: <Child ref="child" />

Comment: obviously you can declare ref when you create a component, my question is to dynamically create a ref during the constructor method.

Comment: this.ref=Math.random(); and <input ref={this.ref} />;

Comment: that doesn't work at all, if you reference my question it's pretty clear how they are supposed to communicate

Answer (score 5):

I needed this exact same thing for a form I was making and this is what I came up with to add the refs to the child components automatically

Given that you have:

```
<Parent>
    <Child />
    <Child />
</Parent>
```

You can use this in the Parent component render function to add a ref to every child.

```
render () {
  let wrappedChildren = [];

  React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, i)=> {
    if (!child) {
      return;
    }
      let refName = 'child' + i
      wrappedChildren.push(React.cloneElement(child, {
        key: refName,
        ref: refName,
      }
    ));
  }, this);
  return (
    <View>
        {wrappedChildren}
    </View>
  )
}
```

This will add a ref to every Child consisting of a string plus the index of the current map and then render them in the same order, giving you the equivalent of doing this:

```
<Parent>
    <Child ref="child0" />
    <Child ref="child1" />
</Parent>
```

I know that string refs are deprecated but i was trying to keep it simple you can also use refs as callbacks by changing:

```
ref: refName
```

to:

```
ref: (c) => { this[refName] = c }
```

And then used it in the parent component as this.child0 for example.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

In this approach the Parent component is the one where the children are being used in render. You can manipulate the childrens' "state" by calling a method of them.

**Parent.js**

```
class Parent extends Component {
  refs = [];

  componentDidMount() {
    this.refs[0].doSelect();
  }

  setRef = ref => {
    this.refs.push(ref);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child ref={this.setRef} />
        <Child ref={this.setRef} />
      </div>
     )
   }
}
```

**Child.js**

```
class Child extends Component {
  state = { isSelected: false }

  doSelect = () => {
    this.setState({ isSelected: true })
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="child" />
  }
}
```