# React, how to access child's state from parent? no need to update parent's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Hi I am pretty new to React and having really hard time wrapping my head around this whole state management and passing data through state and props. I do understand that the standard react way is to pass down data in a unidirectional way- from parent to child, which I have done so for all other components. 
But I have this component called Book, which changes its 'shelf' state, based on user selection form 'read, wantToRead, currentlyReading, and none'. And in my BookList component which renders Book component, but it needs to be able to read Book's shelf state and render the correct books under sections called  'read, wantToRead, currentlyReading, and none'. And since in this case, Book component is being rendered from BookList component and BookList being the parent, i really cannot understand how to enable BookList to access Book's state? 
BookList component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import Book from './Book'

class BookList extends Component {
  render(){
    const { books, shelf } = this.props


    return (
    <div className="list-books">
      <div className="list-books-content">
        <div className="list-books-title">
          <h1>MyReads</h1>
        </div>

        <div className="bookshelf">
          <h2 className="bookshelf-title">None</h2>
          {books.map((book)=> {
            console.log(book)
            if (shelf === ''){
              return <div className="bookshelf-books">
                    {/* <BookStateless book= {book} /> */}
                    <Book book = {book} />
                      {/* <BookStateless book= {book} /> */}
                    </div>

            }
          })}
        </div>


        <div className="bookshelf">
          <h2 className="bookshelf-title">Currently Reading</h2>
            {books.map((book)=> {
              if (shelf === 'currentlyReading'){
                return <div className="bookshelf-books">
                      {/* <BookStateless book= {book} /> */}
                      <Book book = {book} />
                      </div>
              }
              // console.log(this.book.title, this.book.state)
            })}
          </div>

          <div className="bookshelf">
            <h2 className="bookshelf-title">Want to Read</h2>
            {books.map((book)=> {
              if (shelf === 'wantToRead'){
                return <div className="bookshelf-books">
                      {/* <BookStateless book= {book} /> */}
                      <Book book = {book} />
                        {/* <BookStateless book= {book} /> */}
                      </div>
              }
              // console.log(this.book.title, this.book.state)
            })}
          </div>
          <div className="bookshelf">
            <h2 className="bookshelf-title">Read</h2>
            {books.map((book)=> {
              if (shelf === 'read'){
                console.log(shelf)
                return <div className="bookshelf-books">
                      {/* <BookStateless book= {book} /> */}
                      <Book book = {book} />
                      </div>
              }
              // console.log(this.book.title, this.book.state)
            })}
          </div>

      </div>
      <div className="open-search">
        <Link to="/search">Add a book</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default BookList
```

Book component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
// import * as BooksAPI from './BooksAPI'

import Select from 'react-select'
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css'

class Book extends Component {
  state={
    // state can be read, none, want to read, or currently reading
    shelf: ''
  }


  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({ shelf: e['value'] })
    console.log("this?", this)
  }



  render(){
    const { book } = this.props
    const { shelf } = this.state
    console.log("book", book.state)

    const options = [
      { value: 'currentlyReading', label: 'currentlyReading'},
      { value: 'wantToRead', label: 'wantToRead'},
      { value: 'read', label: 'read'},
      { value: 'none', label: 'none'}
    ]

    return (
      <li key={book.id}>
        <div className="book">
          <div className="book-top">
            <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 188, backgroundImage: `url("${book.imageLinks.thumbnail}")` }}></div>
            <div className="book-shelf-changer">

              <Select
                value=""
                options={options}
                onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange(e)}
              />


            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="book-title">{book.title}</div>
          <div className="book-authors">{book.authors}</div>
        </div>
      </li>

    )
  }
}

export default Book
```

in my app.js i have:

```
import React from 'react'
import * as BooksAPI from './BooksAPI'
import './App.css'
import Search from './Search'
import BookList from './BookList'
import Book from './Book'


import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

class BooksApp extends React.Component {


  state = {
    books : []

  }

  componentDidMount(){
    BooksAPI.getAll().then((books)=> {
      this.setState({ books: books })
      // console.log("bookstest",this)
    })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Route exact path="/" render={()=>(
          <Book books={this.state.books} />
        )} />
        <Route path="/search" render={()=>(
          <Search books={this.state.books} />
        )} />
        <Route path="/BookList" render={()=>(
          <BookList books={this.state.books} />
        )} />

      </div>
      )
    }
  }

export default BooksApp
```

Right now, when i open the booklist component in browser, i get no books because it's not picking up the state in any of the if statements here:

```
if (shelf === 'currentlyReading'){
                return <div className="bookshelf-books">
}
```

Thank you so much in advance for reading through and, any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: where u building routing url for booklist?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access child's state in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864951/how-to-access-childs-state-in-react)

Answer (score 15):

You don't need to "access" the child's state, you can pass a callback handler from the parent to the child and when an event is triggered inside the child you can notify the parent through that event handler (callback).
I'll post a small example:

```js
class Book extends React.Component {
  handleClick = e => {
    const { bookId, onToggleBook } = this.props;
    onToggleBook(bookId);
  };

  render() {
    const { name, isRead } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={`${isRead && "read"}`} onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <span>{name}</span>
        {isRead && <i> - You read me</i> }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      books: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "book 1",
          isRead: false
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "book 2",
          isRead: false
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "book 3",
          isRead: true
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "book 4",
          isRead: false
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  onToggleBookStatus = bookid => {
    const { books } = this.state;
    const nextBookState = books.map(book => {
      if (book.id !== bookid) return book;
      return {
        ...book,
        isRead: !book.isRead
      };
    });
    this.setState(prevState => ({ books: nextBookState }));
  };

  render() {
    const { books } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>My Books</div>
        {books.map(book => (
          <Book
            key={book.id}
            isRead={book.isRead}
            name={book.name}
            bookId={book.id}
            onToggleBook={this.onToggleBookStatus}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.read {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Dude, you just gave me the key to unlocking the Wisdom of React in my mind! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

As you know, to pass something from the parent to the child, you use props. To get something from the child to the parent, you again use props, but this time you pass a *function* down to the child, and then the child calls that function.

So for example, you would modify the child's handle change function to something like this:

```
handleChange(e){
  if (this.props.onShelfChanged) {
    this.props.onShelfChanged(e.value);
  }
  this.setState({ shelf: e.value })
}
```

And then in the parent, you'll want to pass an onShelfChanged prop down to the book, so that you can get notified when the value changes. Something like this:

```
// in the render function
{books.map((book, index) => 
    <Book book={book} onShelfChanged={() => this.childBookChanged(index)}
)};
```

And you'll need to create and fill out the childBookChanged function to do whatever updates you need to do.

One thing to be mindful of is that you don't want to be manually keeping the book and the bookshelf in sync. The `Book` is tracking some state of its own, and then you're passing that up and probably altering the state of the bookshelf. Keeping these in sync as your application grows can be a headache and a source of bugs. Instead, you should have one piece of code be in charge, which it looks like will likely be the bookshelf (since it's the topmost component that cares about this state). So most likely you'll want to remove the internal state from `Book`, and instead tell the book what to do via props.

If you need the `Book` component to sometimes work as a standalone and sometimes work inside a bookshelf, then you may need to do a bit more work to get it to support both a "controlled" and "uncontrolled" implementation, but it's still a good idea to move the state up for the controlled case. You can read more about controlled and uncontrolled components [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)