# React router: new component only render on existing view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am trying to switch between two pages, but ran into many problems whiling learning `react router`

Within my `App.js`, there is a bottom, which will navigate me to `Cart` when clicked.

```
  render()  {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary Bottom-right " onClick={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
              Confirmed Order
        </button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-Primary">
          <Link to="/displayCart" >Show Car</Link>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In my cart component, also have similar button that navigtaes me back to the `App` component.

```
class Cart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state={
            cartData:null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.callApi()
          .then(res => this.setState({ cartData: res.express}))
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      }

      callApi = async () => {
          const response = await fetch('/myCart');
          const body = await response.json();
          if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);

          return body;
      };

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="col">
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                    <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to Shopping Center</h1>
                </header>
            </div>
                <div>{ReactHtmlParser(this.state.cartData)}</div>
                <button type="button Bottom-right" className="btn btn-Primary">
                    <Link to="/" >Keep Shopping</Link>
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My index.js contains two components, app JS being the default component.

```
    ReactDOM.render(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <switch>
                <div>
                    <Route exact path="/displayCart" component={Cart}/>
                    <Route component={App} />
                </div>
            </switch>
        </BrowserRouter>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

Now they are really flaw in many levels:

1: When I clicked show cart, instead of rendering the new view. The cart component is rendered on the top of the view with App still rendered.

2: After clicking the Show Cart , I clicked the Show App to get back to my App Component, however the console prints:

```
Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in Cart (created by Route)
```

3: If I changed the state in `App` component when I get back to `App` component from Cart `component`, the state did not get refreshed. For example (For example, the Boolean value "purchase" in items.) When I get back from App component from Cart, the state stays true, instead, I want it to get back to the initial state.

I followed the tutorial but it is just broken. What did i do wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the warning is because `setState` is being called by `<Cart />` even after you go back to the App which means that the cart component is unmounted by then.

You should keep track of when `Cart` becomes unmounted.

You can do this by creating a variable in your `Cart` component such as `_isMounted` and then using the lifecycle event `componentWillUnmount` to keep track.

```
componentWillUnmount(){
   _isMounted =false
}
```

Then just before you use setState, do a quick check to make sure `_isMounted` is true.

```
this.callApi()
          .then(res => if(isMounted){
                         this.setState({ cartData: res.express}))
                       }
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Obviously you need to also change `_isMounted` to true using `ComponentDidMount`

Here is an [article on this topic](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html)

---

In regards to App's state not 'refreshing'... it is because the App component never unmounts and mounts again as you go from App > Cart > App.

To fix this, tell `switch` to only mount the `<App />` component when the url is exactly matching the homepage using `exact path="/"`

```
        <switch>
            <div>
                <Route exact path="/displayCart" component={Cart}/>
                <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
            </div>
        </switch>
```

---

Now, if you want to keep track of the state changes even if  is closed (unmounted) before the API call finishes then you should create a function inside of `<App/>` that does the `setState` for you and pass it as a prop to `<Cart />` and then from inside  You can call this prop function.

This will only work though if you put your React Router stuff inside of

The way I do it is this:
 - index.js always loads 
 - Inside of  I then redirect to the show the proper component

This means that  is always mounted. However it lets me use App's state as the default "main" state that always exists since I never unmount it. So if I have a child component like ... I can give Cart one of 's functions. This function will change the state within  regardless of whether  is still mounted/shown.

If you restructure you app like that then you can do the following:

**App.js** Add a function that will change it's state.

```
changeState(key, value){
   this.setState({
      key : value
   }
}
```

Now pass this function as a prop

```
    <BrowserRouter>
        <switch>
            <div>
                <Route exact 
                       path="/displayCart" 
                       render={
                         (props) => <Cart {...props} 
                         changeStateinApp={this.changeState} /> 
                       }
                  />
                <Route component={App} />
            </div>
        </switch>
    </BrowserRouter>,
```

**Cart.js** Now call this function

```
this.callApi()
          .then(res => 
              this.props.changeStateinApp(cartData, res.express)
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: OK, i got rid of the error. What about the problem of new component does not render on a complete new view?

Comment: I updated my answer. I personally always use the <App /> component as the base empty view. And then render one more view inside of it at a time.

Comment: I dont want to change Cart's state in App tho. These two component will fetch from two different urls. And i dont think that the reason why Cart.js only mount on exist on is because of it.

Comment: Once Cart is unmounted (you go back to App) you can't change its state. Also App cannot access Cart's state.

Comment: Look at this answer from another user's question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632830/react-how-to-access-childs-state-from-parent-no-need-to-update-parents-state?rq=1

Comment: I think in #3 you meant that you setState in App.js and then when you go App > Cart > App, that state you set is missing from App?

Comment: lets say one of the state in App is false. I set it to true. And then i go to cart, and then from cart i go back to App again. The state is still true, however, i want it to go back to its original state.

Comment: Also, using your above code, I got changeStateinApp is not a function error

Comment: Which component gives you that error? when you try to pass it down or when you call it?

Comment: Your state in <App/> persists because it is never unmounted. Try adding `exact path="/"` to your `<Switch/>` and it might unmount <App/> for you.

Comment: yeah adding "exact" fixed both 1 and 3. Now just 2 left.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180954/discussion-between-spencer-ovetsky-and-badrush).