# share value from one component into another in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wysiwyg, react-draft-wysiwyg

I have used "React Draft Wysiwyg" for this. Here in the code below I want to access the value of the variable `value` editor.js file in the desktop.js file. how can I do that?

editor.js:

```
export default class TextEditor extends Component {
render(){
  return(){
        <textarea
          disabled
         value={draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))}
        ></textarea>
    
      
    );
  }
}
```

desktop.js:

```
export const Desktop = () => {

    return (
      
        <div className="splitScreen">
            <TextEditor/>

        </div>
}
```

Comment: You don't, directly. You can `useEffect` to call a method prop passed to `<TextEditor>`, or you lift the editor state up a level, or... There are many ways it *could* be done, really.

Comment: It's not clear from you question hot this two components relates to each other.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864951/how-to-access-a-childs-state-in-react This should solve you problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `useState` in desktop.js, while passing the state of `textValue` and the `setState` function as props to `TextEditor` component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const Desktop = () => {
  const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="splitScreen">
      <TextEditor textValue={textValue} setTextValue={setTextValue} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And then using the two props inside `TextEditor`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg";
import { EditorState, convertToRaw } from "draft-js";
import "./editor.css";
import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";
import draftToHtml from "draftjs-to-html";

export default class TextEditor extends Component {
  state = {
    editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
  };

  onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({
      editorState,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { editorState } = this.state;

    // here you set the textValue state for the parent component
    this.props.setTextValue(
      draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))
    );

    return (
      <div className="editor">
        <Editor
          editorState={editorState}
          toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
          wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
          editorClassName="editorClassName"
          onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
        />
        <textarea
          disabled
          text_value={this.props.textValue} // here you use the textValue state passed as prop from the parent component
        ></textarea>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error:  " TypeError: this.props.setTextValue is not a function "

Comment: @Johnst33 Hi, did you add the two props I displayed in the desktop.js file? `<TextEditor textValue={textValue} setTextValue={setTextValue} />`

Comment: @Johnst33 Make sure you always use `textValue` as `this.props.textValue` inside the `TextEditor` component (e.g. `<p>{this.props.textValue}</p>`), since it is taken from the props passed to it from the parent component (Desktop).

Also, if this was the correct answer for your question, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to pass a function as a props in TextEditor from Desktop component.

Like this  `<TextEditor onChange={this.onChange}>`.

Declare a method in Desktop component as follows

```
onChange = (value) => {
  console.log(value);
}
```

Now call this method in TextEditor component in onEditorStateChange method like this

```
 onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({
      editorState,
    });
    this.props.onChange(draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()));
  };
```

Comment: I am getting the error "onchange is undefined" in TextEditor.js file

Comment: Have you passed it in TextEditor props when you used it in Desktop?

Comment: Like this ```<TextEditor onChange={this.onChange} />```

Comment: Yes I did pass this : <TextEditor onChange={this.onChange} />  in desktop.js file but its still showing this error