# React, update state on an event from a third party control

Tags: javascript, .net, reactjs, reactjs.net

I have a react component `InfoPanel` that I want to update the state of when I click on a third party control `gantt chart`. I have only done this with flux to allow components to communicate with each other. I am not sure how to change the state of the `InfoPanel` Component when the third party control event `onTaskClick`fires.

Here is the event that fires for the third party control.

```
class InfoPanelService {
    constructor() {
        this.InitInfoPanel();

    }

    OnTaskClick() {
        //event from a third party control
        gantt.attachEvent("onTaskClick", function (id, e) {
            var tasks = gantt.getTaskByTime();
            var task = tasks[id];

            //determine the task type and get the data

            return true;
        });
    }
    InitInfoPanel() {
        this.OnTaskClick();
    }
}
```

Here is my `InfoPanel` component

```
var InfoPanel = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return { data: {
            project: {},
            subProject: {},
            activity: {}
        } };
    },

    render: function() {
        return (<div>
                    ...tables with the state values
                    ... too long to post
               </div>

          );
    }
```

});

Should I add something like this to my component? `<InfoPanel OnTaskClick = infoPanelService.OnTaskClick` /> instead of attaching the event right away inside of the constructor and pass in that function from the service as props? This way the component is completely dumb and I can easily throw it and reuse it.

```
onResourceSelect() {
    this.props.OnTaskClick();
},
```

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100774/reactjs-setstate-on-parent-inside-child-component

Comment: @JustinM.Ucar I don't see how this helps me. That event is being fired from a third party control not my parent. I need to be notified when it fires, then inside of my component change the state. I can't attach it to a `DOM element`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to wait till the component is mounted tehn proceed like this since it is a custom/3rd party  triggered event:

```
componentDidMount() {
    //component is mounted/inserted to DOM, 
    // Attach your 3td party/custom event listener
    this.getDOMNode().addEventListener("onTaskClick", ()=>{/*handle it here*/});
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to avoid this but using old school react is kind of a headache.