# Prevent child component from rerendering based on change of state in parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a heck of time with this. I do NOT want my child to re-render when the parents state changes. I've tried to use shouldComponentUpdate in the child component, but for some reason that's not even being invoked.

My issue is this. I have several charts on a grid, I want to update one of the charts configuration settings, which I pass as a prop to the component. The parent, which they all share, updates that childs config, but in the process, the config changes and thus they all re-render.

Why isn't shouldComponentUpdate being invoked? It gets invoked on the parent, so I'm assuming it is invoked where the state changes???

My code looks something like:

Parent - has selectDataType with setState
Child1 - calls selectDataType which was passed down as a prop, which re-renders
Child2 - no changes to it's props, but re-renders, which I need to stop

Parent:

```
selectDataType(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    var cellId = e.currentTarget.dataset.id;
    var cellValue = e.currentTarget.childNodes[0].value;

    var newCells = [];

    newCells = this.state.cells.map(function (cell, i) {
        var newObj = Object.assign({}, cell);

        if (cellId == cell.id) {
            newObj['dataType'] = cellValue;
        }

        return newObj;
    });

    this.setState({
        cells: newCells
    });

    return;
}
```

Child1:

```
export default class Pie extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.create = this.create.bind(this);
}

shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
}

create() {
    return {
        //some data
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ReactECharts
                option={ this.create() }
                style={{ position: "absolute", top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0, height: "100%" }}
                theme="chalk"
                notMerge={ true }
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Child2: exactly like Child1

Comment: shouldComponentUpdate() : [Returning false does not prevent child components from re-rendering when their state changes.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

Comment: How do you render the children in the parent? A possible reason is not giving a static `key` property to the child components. If they're given, say, a random key every time they're rendered, then they'll completely unmount and remount with its new parent properties. So the child component isn't updating, it's remounting. Hence `shouldComponentUpdate` won't be called

Comment: Can you show us the parent's render?

Comment: ahhhh...@Jayce444 that seems reasonable. Let me check it out and get back to you.

Comment: @Jayce444 You're a rockstar :) That did the trick, was using a random key. Thanks for the help. If you want to add that as your answer, I'll upvote and close as answered.

Comment: Alrighty, posted

Comment: Thanks @Jayce444. It solved my problem too. Been pulling my hair out on this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your children are given a static key prop (as for all arrays of components). If they're given a random key, then when the parent re-renders it'll give all the children a new random key (different from their old one). This will make React think it's a completely different component, so the existing one will completely unmount and be remounted (with the new properties). So the child component isn't updating, it's remounting. Hence `shouldComponentUpdate` won't be called.

Answer (score 0):

You might find answers here, for both classes and hooks:
[ReactJS: setState on parent inside child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100774/reactjs-setstate-on-parent-inside-child-component)

Short answer for hooks would be:

- Send parent state and setState in child prop. Lets call those `parentState` and `setParentState`
- In child component:

  - have a `useEffect` which only does something when parentState is updated:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        props.parentStateSetter(childStateValueYouWantToTrack);
    }, [props.parentState, childStateValueYouWantToTrack]);
```

You should check out the link for more information