# How to set state of parent component from a child component in react?

Tags: reactjs, parent-child, react-hooks, setstate, react-component

I have a state in Parent Component that has an Array of patients. My `Child Component 4` is a `Countdown component` (// countdown component renders individually countdown for each patient in the array) and when the countdown gets to <=0,  I would like to reset the patient’s `locationInfo & status` value to be empty string in the patient array. In my parent component, I have `resetPatient` function that maps over the `patient array` and should set the values`(locationInfo & status)` of the patient that has <=0 counter to empty strings. The resetPatient function is passed as props down to my Countdown component(4). In Countdown component I call the `this.props.resetPatient` function when the counter gets to <=0. However, this is not working for me. The state on Parent Component doesn’t change.

`Parent Component 
   - Child Component 1 
    - Child Component 2
     - Child Component 3 
      - Child Component 4`

```
Parent component 

export default class ObservationWorkflow extends React.Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
       this.state = {

         patients = [
           { room: "1", name: 'John', locationInfo: 'TV', status: 'Awake'},
           { room: "2", name: 'Shawn, locationInfo: 'Toilet', status: 'Awake'},
           { room: "3", name: 'Gereth, locationInfo: 'Garden', status: 'Awake'}
          ]
         }
       this.resetPatient = this.resetPatient.bind(this);

 }


    resetPatient = (patient, index) => {

        this.setState(prevState => ({

            patients: prevState.patients.map((patient, i) => {
                if (i === index) {
                    return {
                        ...patient,
                        locationInfo: '', 
                        status: ''
                    };
                }
                return patient;
            }),
        }));
    }

   render() {
      return (
    <Child component(1)={this.resetPatient} // then child component 2 passes it down as props to 3 then 4. 
     )
   }
}
```

```
Countdown component(4)// countdown component renders individually countdown for each patient in the array. 

 export default class ObservationCountDown extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            obsTimeleft: undefined
        };

        this.countDown = this.countDown.bind(this);
        this.startCountdown = this.startCountdown.bind(this);
        this.countDownInterval = null;
    }

    countDown() {

        const { obsTakenTime, patient, index } = this.props; 
        const nextDueTimeForObs = moment(obsTakenTime).add(10, 'minutes'); 

        const nextObservationTime = nextDueTimeForObs.subtract(moment.now()).format('mm');

        if (obsTakenTime) {
            this.setState({ obsTimeleft: nextObservationTime + ' mins' });
        }
        if (Number(nextObservationTime) <= 1) {
            this.props.disablePatientUpdate();
        }
        if (Number(nextObservationTime) <= 0) {
            this.setState({ obsTimeleft: 'Overdue' });
            this.props.enablePatientUpdate();
            clearInterval(this.countDownInterval);

            () => this.props.resetPatient(patient, index); // here i call the function as call back
        }
    }
```

How to set the state of parent component from a child component in react.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100774/reactjs-setstate-on-parent-inside-child-component

Comment: in your component(4), where does index come from? you're not handing it down in your Parent, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not calling `resetPatient`, and that `index` isn't defined in that scope in any case.

I would add an `id` to your patient object and use this to identify which one needs to be reset:

```
 patients = [
       { id:1, room: "1", name: 'John', locationInfo: 'TV', status: 'Awake'},
       { id:2, room: "2", name: 'Shawn, locationInfo: 'Toilet', status: 'Awake'},
       { id:3, room: ... }]
```

and your `resetPatient` would become:

```
 resetPatient = (patient) => {

    this.setState(prevState => ({

        patients: prevState.patients.map(p => {
            if (patient.id === p.id) {
                return {
                    ...p,
                    locationInfo: '', 
                    status: ''
                };
            }
            return p;
        }),
    }));
}
```

Then you can just call:

```
   this.props.resetPatient(patient)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you do not need anymore `this.resetPatient = this.resetPatient.bind(this);` when you are already using arrow function at `resetPatient = (patient, index) => {...}`

Second, pass your callback like this :

```
<Child resetPatient= { this.resetPatient } />
```

and then access it in child as props :

```
 this.props.resetPatient(..., ...)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

try calling the function like this

```
this.props.resetPatient(patient, index);
```

by doing `() => this.props.resetPatient(patient, index);` you are just declaring another function which you have to call again,
you can change it to

```
(() => this.props.resetPatient(patient, index))();
```

But that seems rather unnecessary.