# React TypeError: "x" is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I called a function setTodos from the parent in my child components, but this returns the following error:

> setTodos is not a function

Can you explain me why this happened, thanks a lot. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Form from './components/Form';
import TodoList from './components/TodoList';

function App() {
   const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
   const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
   return (
      <div className="App">
         <header>
            <h1>Phuc's Todo list</h1>
         </header>
         <Form inputText={inputText} todos={todos} setTodos={setTodos}/>
         <TodoList/>
      </div>
   );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from 'react';

const Form = ({inputText, setInputText, todos, setToDos}) => {
   const inputTextHandler = (e) => {
      setInputText(e.target.value);
   }
   const submitTodoHandler = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setToDos([
         ...todos,
         {text: inputText, completed: false, id: Math.randowm()*1000}
      ])
   }
   return (
      ...
   )
}
```

Comment: Hey, If you want to use parent's state function I would suggest use it as wrapper function. You can check this post.. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/29101393/8348558

Comment: Please post all relevant code **in** your question. Screenshots alone are not good enough.

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo in your code while calling the `setTodos` in `child component`

It should be `setTodos` in child instead of `setToDos`. You have capital **D**, It should be small **d**.

As Javascript is case sensitve langauge. So you have to use the exact term.

```
setTodos([//here your code]);
```

Comment: Thank you, so that is it, I should more careful with the typo

Answer (score 0):

In your parent component, `setTodos` need to be a callback if you want to do it that way.

Try with `setTodos={(newTodos) => setTodos(newTodos)}` inside your  of parent component.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the `setTodos` as a `prop` into your **child** component. So, probably you are calling there `setToDos` instead `setTodos`.