Why is set state so slow here?
I have a custom chart with clickable points. After a point is clicked I want to change another component which shows that days commits to show the date of the point being clicked. In the parent component I have date and setDate. The chart component gets the useState function as a prop and the list component gets the date as a prop. When the chart gets clicked the list should change. The functionality works but for some reason this it is really slow. How can I make this faster?
Heatmap:
function Tile({ date, count, idx, setDate }) {

  return (
      <div
        onClick={() => {
          setDate(date);
        }}
      ></div>
  );
}

export default function CustomHeatmap({ data, setDate }) {
   ...

  const days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];
  const dates = createYearArray();

  return (
    <div className="border border-1">
        {dates.map((week, outer_idx) => (
          <Stack gap={1}>
            {week.map((date, inner_idx) => (
              <Tile
                idx={inner_idx + outer_idx * 7}
                date={date}
                count={chartData.get(date) ?? 0}
                setDate={setDate}
              ></Tile>
            ))}
          </Stack>
        ))}
      </Stack>
    </div>
  );
}


List:
export default function CommitByDayList({ data, repoDict, date }) {
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (date) {
      const filtered = data.filter(
        (data) => removeTimeFromDate(data.commitDate) === date
      );
      setCommitCount(filtered.length);
      const contributionActivity = organizeCommitsByRepo(filtered);
      setFilteredData(contributionActivity);
    }
  }, [date]);


  return (
    <div className="" style={{ fontSize: "Large", maxWidth: "500px" }}>
      
        <Accordion
        >
          {filteredData && filteredData.size > 0 ? (
            Array.from(filteredData.keys()).map((repoId, outer_idx) => (
              <AccordionItem eventKey={outer_idx}>
                <Accordion.Header className="">
                  <p className="text-primary me-3 my-auto">
                    {repoDict[repoId]}
                  </p>
                  <p
                    className="text-secondary my-auto"
                    style={{ fontSize: "small" }}
                  >
                    {filteredData.get(repoId).length} commits
                  </p>
                </Accordion.Header>
              
              </AccordionItem>
            ))
          ) : (
            <p className="text-dark text-center">No commits today</p>
          )}
        </Accordion>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


The parent
export default function TeamMember() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(today)

...

return (<div>
  <CommitByDayList data={commitData} repoDict={repos} date={date}/>
  <CustomHeatmap data={commitData} setDate={setDate}/> 
</div>
}

When I had a Form control inside the list component (date and setDate where also inside the list component) it worked perfectly fine without delays. But when I made the date a prop and passed this way it slowed down. However this is not really what I am looking for since I want the dates to be selected from the chart, not a form control.
      <div className="d-flex mb-2 flex-row-reverse">
        <Form.Control
          className="border-2"
          style={{ width: "50%" }}
          size="lg"
          type="date"
          placeholder="DateRange"
          value={date}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setDate(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </div>

Here is what the page looks like for better visualization.

It's a lot of code here, you should try to isolate your problem and only post the minimum amount of code that reproduces it. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Modified it to be shorter after comment.

I moved the list component inside the chart component (so I am not setting state from child component) and now I it is not slow anymore. So it is fixed. Although now I have coupled the components.

Maybe it's the way you were setting the state from the child component? This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100774/reactjs-setstate-on-parent-inside-child-component

Needs codesandbox to properly diagnose. But on first glance: 1. There are missing stable key props on all the cases of iterating in the JSX. 2. Theres a big red flag in you are setting state in effects. That is computed state, and should be useMemo. No new state necessary. 3. MIssing code around this so cant be more specific but possible opportunity to optimize the filtering logic, or utilise incremental caching. How many entries (commits) are we dealing with here roughly?
