# React - Passing State between siblings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

Basically new to React, I'm a bit confused on how to properly pass states between components. I found a similar question already [React – the right way to pass form element state to sibling/parent elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147331/react-the-right-way-to-pass-form-element-state-to-sibling-parent-elements)
but I wonder if you can give me a specific answer for the code below.

Currently the structure of the app includes:

- parent component - `App`
- 2 childs: `SearchBar` and `RecipesList`

The goal is to make an async search on my Meteor collection and display only the `recipes` that match the search term.

Right now, I'm just showing all the recipes in my Meteor collection.
I've created a stateful component named `SearchBar` which holds the input value as `this.state.term`. The idea is to pass the state to `RecipesList` but I'm not sure if it's the right thing to do. Alternatively I'd let `App` deal with the state and passing it to the childs. I believe this is a very common scenario, how do you do it?

`App`

```
class App extends Component {

render( ) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar/>
            <SearchBar/>
            <RecipesList/>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

`SearchBar`

```
export default class SearchBar extends Component {

constructor( props ) {
    super( props );

    this.state = {
        term: ''
    };
}

onInputChange( term ) {
    this.setState({ term });
}

render( ) {
    return (
        <div className=" container-fluid search-bar">
            <input value={this.state.term} onChange={event => this.onInputChange(event.target.value.substr( 0, 50 ))}/>
            Value: {this.state.term}
        </div>
    );
}

}
```

`RecipesList`

```
const PER_CLICK = 5;

class RecipesList extends Component {

componentWillMount( ) {
    this.click = 1;
}

handleButtonClick( ) {
    Meteor.subscribe('recipes', PER_CLICK * ( this.click + 1 ));
    this.click++;
}

renderList( ) {
    return this.props.recipes.map(recipe => {
        return (
            <div key={recipe._id} className="thumbnail">
                <img src={recipe.image} alt="recipes snapshot"/>
                <div className="caption">
                    <h2 className="text-center">{recipe.recipeName}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    });
}

render( ) {
    return (
        <ul className="list-group">
            {this.renderList( )}
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick.bind( this )} className="btn btn-default">More</button>
            </div>
        </ul>
    );
}
}

// Create Container and subscribe to `recipes` collection
export default createContainer( ( ) => {
Meteor.subscribe( 'recipes', PER_CLICK );
return {recipes: Recipes.find({ }).fetch( )};
}, RecipesList );
```

Comment: See similar question and answer with using react state hook: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147331/react-the-right-way-to-pass-form-element-state-to-sibling-parent-elements/58965261#58965261

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`App`

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props, ctx){
    super(props, ctx)

    this.state = {
      searchQuery: ''
    }

    this.searchInputChange = this.searchInputChange.bind(this)
  }

  searchInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      searchQuery: event.target.value.substr( 0, 50 )
    })
  }

  render( ) {
    const { searchQuery } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar/>
        <SearchBar onChange={this.searchInputChange} value={searchQuery}/>
        <RecipesList searchQuery={searchQuery}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The `App` component takes care of the state and this is then passed down to the children as props the seach term is available to `RecipesList` through props.searchQuery.

The `searchInputChange` handler is passed down to the `SearchBar` as props.

`SearchBar`

```
export default const SearchBar = ({value, onChange}) => (
  <div className=" container-fluid search-bar">
    <input value={value} onChange={onChange}/>
    Value: {value}
  </div>
)
```

Since the `SearchBar` delegated state to the parent component, we can use a stateless react component as we only need information from the props to render it.

In general it is always best to have a `logical` or `stateful` or `controller` component take care of state and the logic, this component then passes down state and methods to `presentational` or `view` components which take care of what the user sees and interacts with.

Answer (score 0):

Define the state `term` up in to the App component.
Also write the handleInput function and pass it to the SearchBar component as porps

```
handleInput(val) {
this.setState({
    term: val,
});
}
```

When something in the search bar is typed(onKeyUp) add the listener handleInput.

Also create `<RecipesList searchQuery={this.state.term}/>`

now in the render function RecipesList filter out the recipes you want to display from your list