# Sibling component's communication in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've run into an interesting scenario where I need to let the Child2's method be called by Child1.

```
export class Parent extends React.Component{ 

child2: Child2; // has a reloadChild2 method

...  

<Child1 reloadSibling={this.child2.reloadChild2}>
...

}
```

I'm trying to create an instance of Child2 and pass its method as a prop to Child1. I'm not sure if this is the way to go about.

Comment: show me the function

Comment: It is not the way to go in the proper React way. You may need to change your composition.

Answer (score 0):

These questions and answers helped me to understand the various options we have:

[ReactJS Two components communicating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285923/reactjs-two-components-communicating)

[React – the right way to pass form element state to sibling/parent elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147331/react-the-right-way-to-pass-form-element-state-to-sibling-parent-elements)