# getting error when exporting variable in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, variables

hello i have this component in react js :

```
import React from 'react';
import './Questions.css';

const Questions = (props) => {
    

    let questions = Object.keys(props.slices).map((questionKey, i) => (
        <li key={i}>
            <p>{props.slices[questionKey].question}</p>
            <div className="Answer">
                <input
                onChange={props.selectScore(questionKey)} 
                type="range" 
                min="1" 
                max="10" 
                value={props.slices[questionKey].transform === '1' ? '10' : props.slices[questionKey].transform.replace('0.','')} 
                className="rangeInput"
                style={{background: props.slices[questionKey].fill}} />
                <span className="Score" style={{backgroundColor: props.slices[questionKey].fill}}>
                    <div className="leftArrow" style={{borderRight: '5px solid ' + props.slices[questionKey].fill}}></div>
                   <span className="Score" style={{backgroundColor: props.slices[questionKey].fill}}>
                    {/* <div className="leftArrow" style={{borderRight: '5px solid ' + props.slices[questionKey].fill}}></div> */}
                    {props.slices[questionKey].transform === '1' ? '10' : props.slices[questionKey].transform.replace('0.','')}
                  </span>
                </span>

 
            </div>

        </li>
        
    ));
    
    return (
        <>
           
            My variable = {props.slices[2].transform === '1' ? '10' : props.slices[2].transform.replace('0.','')}

            {questions}
        </>
    );

    
    
}


export default Questions;
```

i need to export this line which is in the return function: `{props.slices[2].transform === '1' ? '10' : props.slices[2].transform.replace('0.','')}`
as a variable to use it in another component .
so i did this :

```
export const V = (value) => (
  value === {props.slices[2].transform === '1' ? '10' : props.slices[2].transform.replace('0.','')}
)
```

but i'm getting this error : ***Unexpected token, expected "," (47:20)***
could someone help me to export the variable . thank you in advance

Comment: `V` has invalid syntax. Can you explain the logic of `V`?

Comment: Apart from syntax, you can't (and shouldn't) pass props data to other components that way. See [What's the right way to pass form element state to sibling/parent elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147331/whats-the-right-way-to-pass-form-element-state-to-sibling-parent-elements)

Comment: @MoshFeu v is the name of the variable

Comment: Nope. `V` (upper case) is a function name which throws an error. In order to try to help you fixing the syntax, I need to understand what's its logic.

Comment: @MoshFeu the return of this `{props.slices[2].transform === '1' ? '10' : props.slices[2].transform.replace('0.','')}`  is a number that I want to display in a page

Comment: If so it should return `props.slices[2].transform === '1' ? '10' : props.slices[2].transform.replace('0.','')`. But this function also gets `value`. What it should do with it? If nothing, then remove it - `export const V = () => (...`

Comment: The function syntax is largely academic, it's never going to work anyway. `props` is available only inside the component and you can't export anything from there.

Comment: @GuyIncognito do you have a suggestion to have the ability to use it in another component ?

Comment: Pass the same prop to all components that use it, then export a generic function from somewhere that takes the prop as a parameter. `export const V = (value) => value === '1' ? '10' : value.replace('0.','')` and then `V(props.slices[2].transform)` wherever you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote

> i need to export this line which is in the return function: `{props.slices[2].transform === '1' ? '10' : props.slices[2].transform.replace('0.','')}` as a variable to use it in another component

I assume, you don't want to render anything in this component rather just want to return some computed values? Right? If Yes, then you shoould simple return the values like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import './Questions.css';

const Questions = (props) => {
    
    // better to use const instead of let, if you don't need to modify a variable...
    const questions = Object.keys(props.slices).map((questionKey, i) => (
        <li key={i}>
            <p>{props.slices[questionKey].question}</p>
            <div className="Answer">
                <input
                onChange={props.selectScore(questionKey)} 
                type="range" 
                min="1" 
                max="10" 
                value={props.slices[questionKey].transform === '1' ? '10' : props.slices[questionKey].transform.replace('0.','')} 
                className="rangeInput"
                style={{background: props.slices[questionKey].fill}} />
                <span className="Score" style={{backgroundColor: props.slices[questionKey].fill}}>
                    <div className="leftArrow" style={{borderRight: '5px solid ' + props.slices[questionKey].fill}}></div>
                   <span className="Score" style={{backgroundColor: props.slices[questionKey].fill}}>
                    {/* <div className="leftArrow" style={{borderRight: '5px solid ' + props.slices[questionKey].fill}}></div> */}
                    {props.slices[questionKey].transform === '1' ? '10' : props.slices[questionKey].transform.replace('0.','')}
                  </span>
                </span>

 
            </div>

        </li>
        
    ));
    
    const myVar = props.slices[2].transform === '1' ? '10' : props.slices[2].transform.replace('0.','');

    return {myVar,questions};    
    
}


export default Questions;
```

And if you return the values like this `return (<>  ... some JSX ... </>);` then it will be some rendered JSX, which I think you can't simple export as variable to be used by another component.

**Update**

To use myVar in another component do this

```
import Questions from 'questions-file-name';

const selectScore= (key)=>{
// do something with score using key
}

const {myVar,questions} = Questions(slices,selectScore);
```

Comment: thank you sir, now if i want to use myVar in another component i think i should just import this component and write {{myVar}} in the div that i want to show ?