# I'm trying to put api data in a slide, but there is a problem

Tags: reactjs, react-component

App.js

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import Header from './components/Header'
import Slide from './components/Slide'
import Body from './components/Body'
import Footer from './components/Footer'
import './App.css'
import axios from 'axios'

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      movieObj:[] //State to put the received API data
    }
  }


  getMovies=async()=>{
    //화살표함수
      await axios({
      method:'get',
      url:'/v1/search/movie.json?query="스파이더맨"&display=6',
      dataType:'json',
      headers:{
        "X-Naver-Client-Id":'pcSk4iqo1SpsvR7nh1Ul',
        "X-Naver-Client-Secret":'g8wy7q0lQ7'
      }
    })
    .then(response => 
      {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.data.items);
        this.setState({
          movieObj:response.data.items
        })
      }
    )
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getMovies()//호출
  }


  render() {
    console.log(this.state.movieObj)
    console.log(1)
    return (
      <div id="app">
        <Header></Header>
        <Slide  list={this.state.movieObj}></Slide>//Passing api data to sub-component Slide
        <Body></Body>
        <Footer></Footer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Slide.js

```
import {Component} from 'react';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import { Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay, A11y } from 'swiper';
import '../css/slide.css'


// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import 'swiper/css/scrollbar';  

export default class Slide extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      slideObj:this.props.list//State to receive (this.props.list) from App.js
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.slideObj)
    return (
        <Swiper id="slide"
            modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay, A11y]}
            spaceBetween={50}
            slidesPerView={4}
            loop= {true}
            //dir="ltr"//슬라이드 진행방향 전환.. 
            navigation// prev,next
            autoplay={{delay: 2000, disableOnInteraction:false}}
            pagination={{ clickable: true }}
            onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
            onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
            >
            <SwiperSlide className="item">
                <div id='movieInfo'>
                    Slide1
                </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide className="item">Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide className="item">Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide className="item">Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide className="item">Slide 5</SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide className="item">Slide 6</SwiperSlide>
        </Swiper>
    )
  }
}
```

I tried to put an api image inside a slide.
Before putting image inside a slide, I checked whether the data received by axios is properly passed. but
an empty array was output as a result of sending it to the subcomponent.
[App.js - movieObj] (props)-> [Slide.js - slideObj]

How can I pass the apidata received from the parent component to the subcomponent?
The help of the seniors is desperately needed. TT

Comment: I believe you have to add an `onUpdate` method on the parent component in order to propagate its state changes, as in `onUpdate (movieObj) { this.setState({ movieObj }) }`? Taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147331/react-the-right-way-to-pass-form-element-state-to-sibling-parent-elements).

Comment: @Moa
render Even if you put the code mentioned below and run it, only an empty array is output.

Comment: What does `console.log(response.data.items)` prints on the console?

Comment: @Moa
The data received from the api request is displayed.
→ console.log result
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0 : { title : spiderman, link :https://movie.naver.com/movie~ ,image : {imageLink} ... }
~ 6 : { title:{movieName}, link : {movieSite}, image : {imageLink} ... }

Comment: @Moa 
In the code above, I set the path to send the api request to the proxy in the package.json file.
like this.. "proxy":"https://openapi.naver.com", in package.json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you've forgotten to add an `<img />` element on each `SwiperSlide`.

To dynamically render the images retrieved from the API request, we'll have to map (or loop) through the `this.state.slideObj` array so we can populate attributes such as `id`, `src` and `alt` with data returned from `getMovies()`.

I've omitted bits of code to keep it nimble:

```
export default class Slide extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      slideObj: this.props.list,
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Swiper id="slide" ... >
        {this.state.slideObj.map(data => (
          <SwiperSlide className="item">
            <img src={data.image.imageLink} alt={data.title} />
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
    )
  }
}
```

Let me know how it goes?

Cheers

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
Thanks to you, the webpage behaves the way you want it to.
I learned a lot.